# How to Capture Comma Delimited Hex values in URL and Replace Commas with Dashes using Htaccess Rewrites

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect an old url to a new url by using Htaccess Rewriting. The old url that I'm redirecting contains hex values separated by commas. There can be 1-5 hex values in the url.

Old URL:

```
/colors/8e39ef,3626af,3169d1,ffffff,ff00ff/
```

Final URL:

```
/hex/8e39ef-3626af-3169d1-ffffff-ff00ff/
```

My starting regex is this: `\/colors\/([0-9A-Za-z -]+)(,[0-9A-Za-z -]+)*\/`, but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: What you call the "Old URL" actually is not a valid URL...

Comment: Let's stay on topic. This question is not about if a url is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule colors hex
RewriteRule (.*),(.*) $1-$2 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

You can change `http://example.com` to an appropriate domain

**Input URL**

> http://local.colorify.com/colors/sdfd,sdfadsfds,adsfasdf/

**URL after rewrite applied**

> http://local.colorify.com/hex/sdfd-sdfadsfds-adsfasdf/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my goal is to use Htaccess rewrites to handle this...

Comment: Sorry that, I got it wrong, I have updated the answer. Please, check.

Comment: what's the result?

Comment: My input URL was like http://local.colorify.com/colors/sdfd,sdfadsfds,adsfasdf/ and I was redirected to http://local.colorify.com/hex/sdfd-sdfadsfds-adsfasdf/. Isn't it something you are up to?